# multiple instances of a class, programmatically, flutter-dart

Tags: flutter, dart

My project consists of using WebSocket to communicate with devices, the data of which is stored using hive. Illustrate this hierarchy.

Hive -> Foo() -> each foo communicates over a websocket.

If my Foo() requirements go over 100, what would be the best way to manage them? As while some screen requires showing details about a specific Foo() (let's say the one communicating at IP xxx.xxx.x.xx)

What would be the best way to achieve this design using Flutter?

Comment: The question isn't clear enough.

Comment: If I had to make a class instance say `Star()` for each star in the universe, how would I manage that programmatically?

Answer (score -1):

You can put your instances in a collection like a List or a Map.

Comment: but sooner or later it'll get complex and hard to manage